# I want to create a box and button in WordPress, where user will put post ID to load the post

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want a javascript code that will take an input as Post ID and add the id to this default url (https:bemaearn.xyz/?p=) so that the submit button will load the post on WordPress. A user can access any post using the post ID

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you need javascript.

```
<form action="/">
<input type="text" id="posts" name="p"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```